# How can I get iOS Device hardware specification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

what's the best way to get info about iOS device CPU, GPU and memory from code? 
I want to get how many cores does it have, how many  GHz does cpu has and so on..
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Probably so he can scale processing power for his application?

Comment: I'm writing a game and I need to know if this device has low hardware specifications, so then I will be able to disable some effects..

Comment: There are 11 devices supporting the latest iOS. I can't be that difficult to exclude them by their model names. (@Jimbo So scaling makes no real sense)

Comment: This is not off-topic. He's asking how to get these specs *from code*, and included the `objective-c` tag. This question may be a dupe, or poorly-researched ahead of time, but off-topic it is not.

Comment: It is possible to get this information in Android and now I need it for iOS too..

Comment: `0Silencer` iOS isn't Android don't think because you can do it in Android it must mean (it is possible) you can do it in iOS. Apple are very restrictive about what developers can and can't do where as it is a little bit more relaxed with Android. @Jimbo just want to say Hi, haven't seen you since Uni.

Answer (score 8):

You don't get the device CPU, GPU and memory information through your code. You read [UIDevice developer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/name) and get other information using it:

```
UIDevice *device  = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *name    = [device name];
NSString *sysname = [device systemName]; 
NSString *model   = [device model];
```

And possibly even more tricky specifications, and then you refer to the Wikipedia [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) article to look up the hardware specifications of each model.

Comment: +1, since there's a very finite list of iOS hardware, I would just map a set of features to each model. If you encounter a model you don't recognize, assume it's new and go for the high end.

Comment: I know that UIDevice can't get me that information, and that's why I'm asking about if there is some way to get it. Also, it could be done in Android, and I think there must be some way..

Comment: I think you're over-complicating the problem. (XY) *You* need to know what graphics settings to apply, *not* what the CPU/GPU speed is. That's just an implementation detail, is it not? What about just using the hardware model is problematic?

Comment: This answer is really useless and I wonder why do people upvote it.

Comment: Why do you find it useless @0Silencer? As `Craig Otis` mentioned, there are only finite number of iOS devices being supported by each SDK. You get the specs and detect the hardware specs based on that. Nothing further can be done for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

My comments remain from above about just because you can do something in Android don't expect to be able to do it in iOS. Apple are very restrictive about what they allow developers to do where as it is a bit more relaxed with Android.

But to answer your question I believe you a can detect the amount of cores a device has by using one of two methods, please note whilst I have tested this code I have never submitted it to the Apple App Store so I don't know if it will pass or not, you do that at your own risk.

Method 1 for getting the number of cores uses the [`mach_host.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/osfmk/mach/mach_host.defs) for counting the number of cores.

```
#include <mach/mach_host.h>    

int numberOfCores()
{
   host_basic_info_data_t info;
   mach_msg_type_number_t count; 

   count = HOST_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
   host_info(mach_host_self(), HOST_BASIC_INFO, (host_info_t)&info, &count);
   return info.max_cpu;
}
```

Method 2 for getting the number of cores uses the [`sysct1.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-84/configd.tproj/configd_server.h?txt) for counting the number of cores

```
#include <sys/sysct1.h> 

unsigned int numberOfCores() 
{
   size_t len;
   unsigned int ncpu;
   len = sizeof(ncpu);
   sysctlbyname("hw.ncpu", &ncpu &len, NULL, 0);       

   return ncpu;
}
```

You could also replace `sysctlbyname("hw.ncpu", &ncpu &len, NULL, 0);` with `sysctlbyname("hw.physicalcpu", &ncpu &len, NULL, 0);` to obtain the physical cores.

In all honesty I'm not sure whether `<mach/mach_host.h>` and `<sys/sysct1.h>` are private libraries or not so this really is use at your own risk.

Comment: Is it possible to get the The name and model number of the sensors & The maximum range of the sensor in the sensor's unit.The current consumption  by this sensor while in use ??

Comment: @siva if it is possible I'm not sure how to do that but that does seem like something apple would stop you at. Sorry I can't be any help